# Long Shanghai Layover

Tags: layovers, shanghai, disney

I have a 15 hour layover in Shanghai. I arrive at PVG at 6am and depart for the USA at 9pm. I want to visit Disneyland Shanghai. What time should I leave DL to ensure enough time to get back, through security and onto my connecting flight? Is taxi the best travel option? I will be getting a 144 hour visa on arrival and will not have luggage as it will be checked through - hoping to leave carry on stored at the airport. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disneyland and PVG airport or relatively close (by Shanghai standards). Easiest would be a taxi. For a 9pm departure, I would probably leave Disneyland around 6pm (actual departure from the site, NOT  "starting your to make your way to the exit").

See more details at https://www.topchinatravel.com/shanghai/how-to-get-to-shanghai-disney-resort.htm